# “Always available offline” includes not all files

Tags: windows-xp

I use the "Always available offline" option to have some network dirs always available on my notebook.

However, some dirs are not available offline, even if they are marked.
First I thought there is some max. size for offline dirs, but I did not find such an config setting.

Any hints?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on a corporate network, it is possible for network administrators to make some files / folders unavailable offline. I can imagine this being done on data that many users had access to and could all feasibly modify the data offline and then have  anightmare trying to sync it all back up.

Comment: Well, it is on a corporate network, but on a project dir, where only a couple of people have access to

Comment: @Simon - I'd ask the IT dept if this is deliberate? They may have another method of sharing these files / folders set up. They might not want anyone to work on them outside of the offices for security purposes etc.. They will be able to answer you with more details than I can though.